# Wordpress: Add Element as a Filter to 'the_content'

Tags: wordpress

Can I and How would I add a filter in the function.php that would add a HTML element around the content when the_content is used? This would be similar to what you can do with the_title. i.e:

```
the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' );
```

What I need is to add a section element around the content containing a class similar to:

```
the_content('<section class="content_wrap">', '</section>');
```

I know I can:

```
<section class="content_wrap">
    <?php the_content ?>
</section>
```

But if I can filter it in, it would GREATLY reduce the number of php open and close tags by minimizing a lot of the code in the template files [and also i can mindlessly code more w/o having to remember to add the tags - LOL].

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```
function content_filter($content) {
    return '<section class="content_wrap">' . $content . '</section>';
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'content_filter', 6);
```

I hope that will help you :)

Doc : http://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-something-to-the_content

Comment: I did and I think I just had a type-o b4.  LOL  Thnx!